# Integration between different Google Appmaker Apps

Tags: google-app-maker

I'd like to be able to switch between 2 different apps (app1 and app2) using and transition animation. Ideally with the following capabilities
1) App2 is able to recognize that was invoked by App1
2) App1 able to received a callback parameter from App2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no magic for this case. To implement this scenario you need to:

1 Create separate model (AppSettings for example) in both apps and store there App1Url and App2Url correspondingly for each app.

2 To navigate user from App1 to App2 you can use this binding for Link widgets:

```
@datasources.AppSettings.item.App2Url + '?paramName=paramValue' + '#PageName'
```

3 In the onAttach event of the 'PageName' page invoke function like this

```
function loadPageName() {
  google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
     var paramName = location.parameter.paramName;
     var datasource = app.datasources.SomeDatasource;

     datasource.filters.SomeField._equals = paramName;
     datasource.load();
  });
}
```

Please, keep in mind, that to avoid double datasource loading you need to switch it to [manual loading mode](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#automatically_load_data).

This scenario will cause full page reload.