# How can I get the URL in Google AppMaker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to get the current URL in an AppMaker app.  However, the standard JavaScript ways do not work, ScriptApp is not available in AppMaker, and the objects that *are* in AppMaker do not return the correct URL (that starts with https://script.google.com).

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You  can add AppSettings model with AppUrl field and init it on app start on server side. Here is link to detailed technique description: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904477/integration-between-different-google-appmaker-apps/41905378#41905378

Comment: In case, you only need URL parameters you can check this App Script API: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/url#getlocationfunction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run a backend/serverside script and use Apps Script

```
ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()
```

See the doc [ScriptApp Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/service)

Comment: Returns the URL of the web app, if it has been deployed; otherwise returns null.

Answer (score 4):

To have an app URL on client side, you can load it during app startup. Firstly, let's create **server script** that returns app URL:

```js
/**
 *  Get the URL of the published web app.
 */
function getAppUrl() {
  return ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
}
```

Open your **Project settings** and put next code to **App startup script** section:

```js
loader.suspendLoad();

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(url) {
  appUrl = url;
  loader.resumeLoad();
}).getAppUrl();
```

[image: screenshot]

Now you are able to use **appUrl** everywhere in **Client Scripts**.

Using this approach you can create initial app config on startup that requires specific data from server.