# Call a Google App Maker App with a parameter

Tags: google-app-maker

Hello i am new here so if i ask a stupid question please forgive me.

We at AppAtSchool are working with Google ApMaker and we want to call a published App with 2 parameters. How can we read those in App Maker? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to elaborate and provide more information on what exactly you want to achieve and have tried already but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing, that you are trying to read page URL parameters. In this case you can pass parameters like this:

```
https://script.google.com/<SomeMagic>/exec/?param1=value1&param2=value2#PageName
```

And then read them in page onAttach event(https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/logic#events):

```
google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
  var params = location.parameter;
  var param1 = params.param1;
  var param2 = params.param2;

  // Use parameters...
});
```

Maybe you also will need a way to genarate such links with parameters:

[Integration between different Google Appmaker Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904477/integration-between-different-google-appmaker-apps/41905378#41905378)

Answer (score 1):

you can call your application with url something like this: script.google.com/blablabla/#viewname/paramValue, and take param on client side and send it to server side.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrey

Answer (score 0):

If you pass parameters to your App Maker app through URL parameters, your app can read the parameters using the google.script.url.getLocation method:

```
google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
  console.log(location.parameters);
  console.log(location.hash);
});
```

Find more details [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/url)