# Get a Google App Make application open to not only a specific page but also a specific record?

Tags: google-app-maker

How do get a Google App Make application open to not only a specific page/form in Google App Maker but also a specific record within that page?

Answer (score 0):

There are different techniques to achieve this behavior and for sure the implementation will depend on your requirements.

- if you want your app's URL to display current state and make this URL shareable, then you need to read this: [Integration between different Google Appmaker Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904477/)
- if you don't care about shareable URL **and** you have common datasource for your list and details pages, then you can just update selected record in your list and navigate user to the details page:

```js
// row's or row descendant's onClick event
app.datasources.ItemsList.selectKey(widget.datasource.item._key);
app.showPage(app.pages.ItemDetails);
```

- if you have dedicated datasource for you details page, then your code can look like this:

```js
// row's or row descendant's onClick event
var detailsDs = app.datasources.ItemDetails;
detailsDs.unload();
detailsDs.query.filters._key._equals = widget.datasource.item._key;
app.showPage(app.pages.ItemDetails);
```

You need to unload details datasource to prevent blinking (showing previous item, if you are viewing item by item). By the way, you can also unload datasource in onDetach event of the details page.